# Как замерить время выполнения части кода в C?

Tags: c, профилирование

Например, для функции:

```
int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <time.h>

time_t t0 = time(0);
/* some long calculation */
time_t t1 = time(0);
double time_in_seconds = difftime(t1, t0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить о мире Unix, то можно использовать gprof профайлер.

Comment: Не могли бы вы объяснить по-подробней?

Answer (score 0):

Можно так.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/times.h>

int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

double measure () {
    struct tms begin, end;

    /* Начать измерение */
    times(&begin);

    /* Выполнить измеряемое действие */
    add(0, 0);

    /* Завершить измерение */
    times(&end);

    return (double)(end.tms_utime - begin.tms_utime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если пишите для Win32, то лучше всего воспользоваться высокоточными функциями, такими, как, например, QueryPerformanceCounter или timeGetTime. Для Linux - тоже копать в направлении счетчиков производительности процессора... Я лично для реализации использовал QueryPerformanceCounter и частично исходный код вот этой статьи:

[Pixel Graphics Programming on Windows Mobile](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/Caleidoscope.aspx)

-там можно разобраться что и как работает. К сожалению, это было давно, и сейчас у меня нет на руках тех исходников.

Однако, для тривиальных функций, как в Вашем примере, я не вижу особого смысла для замера производительности (наверное, это просто взято как пример).